# How to name a coffeescript file for a Rails 3.1+ namespaced controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

If I have a Rails 3.1+ controller called PeopleController and a second one for admin functions called Admin::PeopleController, how should I name and/or construct the associated coffeescript files to be picked up unambiguously when a given controller is hit?

It seems for the standard people controller, I should create people.js.coffee - that makes sense. How do I name the coffeescript file that will get loaded for the admin people controller? Is there a naming convention I can follow, or does the one coffeescript file need to be used for both?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it doesn't really matter what you call them. If you're requiring the whole tree, or at least specifying the files you want to include, in your `application.js` file then they'll all get picked up anyways.

If you're including the files individually then you'd still need to specify, presumably in your layout file, which one(s) you're including with the usual stylesheet tag.

I guess the convention would be to name them `people.js.coffee` and `admin_people.js.coffee`.